# Powershell - Script working outside of funciton but not inside of it

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to write a simple function that gets Backup information from Azure for my VMs and then outputs it. I came up with this as below. It works if it is not placed in a function and when placed in one it only runs but the variable `$vmBackupReport` is just Empty. I need to place it in a function so that I can run two separate queries for Prod and Test. The script runs without an error either way.

```
Function createReport {
    Write-Host "Collecing Azure virtual machine Information" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
        if(!(gc $path)) {
            Write-Host "Please provide a List of the virtual Machines in this file: 'C:\VmListFlurin.txt'" -BackgroundColor Red
            exit 1
        }
        $vms = @()
        foreach ($vmname in gc $path)
        {
            $vms += Get-AzVM -Name $vmname

            if(!(Get-AzVM -Name $vmname)) {
                Write-Host "VM $($vmname) not found, check VM name and Subscription and try again!" -BackgroundColor Red
            }
            
        }
 
        if($vms) {
            Write-Host "Collecting all Backup Recovery Vault information" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
        }
        else {
            exit 1
        }

        $backupVaults = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault

    #---------------Part 2

    $vmBackupReport = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    foreach ($vm in $vms) 
    {
        $recoveryVaultInfo = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupStatus -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Type 'AzureVM'
        if ($recoveryVaultInfo.BackedUp -eq $true)
        {
            Write-Host "$($vm.Name) - BackedUp : Yes"

            $vmBackupVault = $backupVaults | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq $recoveryVaultInfo.VaultId}


            $container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM -VaultId $vmBackupVault.ID -FriendlyName $vm.Name 
            $backupItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $container -WorkloadType AzureVM -VaultId $vmBackupVault.ID

            #---------------Get All available restore points-------------------------#
            $rententionDays = 730
            $vaultName = $vmBackupVault.Name
            $vaultResourceGroup = $vmBackupVault.ResourceGroupName
            $friendlyName = $vm.name

 
            $vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $vaultResourceGroup -Name $vaultName
            $Container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM -Status Registered -FriendlyName $friendlyName -VaultId $vault.ID
            $BackupItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $Container -WorkloadType AzureVM -VaultId $vault.ID
 
            $startingPoint = -25
            $finishingPoint = 0
            $jobsArray = @()
 
            Do {
 
            $StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($startingPoint)
            $EndDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($finishingPoint)
            $RP = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $BackupItem -StartDate $Startdate.ToUniversalTime() -EndDate $Enddate.ToUniversalTime() -VaultId $vault.ID
            $jobsArray += $RP
            $startingPoint = $startingPoint - 25
            $finishingPoint = $finishingPoint -25
            }until($startingPoint -le -($retentionDays))
 
            #$jobsArray | FT -AutoSize -Property RecoveryPointid, RecoveryPointTime, RecoveryPointType
            #---------------Get All available restore points-------------------------#

            [void]$vmBackupReport.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
            VM_Name = $vm.Name
            VM_ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
            VM_BackedUp = $recoveryVaultInfo.BackedUp
            VM_RecoveryVaultName =  $vmBackupVault.Name
            VM_RecoveryVaultPolicy = $backupItem.ProtectionPolicyName
            VM_BackupHealthStatus = $backupItem.HealthStatus
            VM_BackupProtectionStatus = $backupItem.ProtectionStatus
            VM_LastBackupStatus = $backupItem.LastBackupStatus
            VM_LastBackupTime = $backupItem.LastBackupTime
            VM_BackupDeleteState = $backupItem.DeleteState
            VM_BackupLatestRecoveryPoint = $backupItem.LatestRecoveryPoint
            RecoveryVault_ResourceGroupName = $vmBackupVault.ResourceGroupName
            VM_AllRecoveryPoints = $jobsArray.RecoveryPointTime
        }) 

        

        } 
        else 
        {
            Write-Host "$($vm.Name) - BackedUp : No" -BackgroundColor DarkRed
            $vmBackupVault = $null
            $container =  $null
            $backupItem =  $null
        } 
        
        
    }
}

$path = "C:\VmListTest.txt"
Set-AzContext -Subscription "Test/PreProd" | out-null
createReport;

$path = "C:\VmListProd.txt"
Set-AzContext -Subscription "Produktion" | out-null
createReport;

$vmBackupReport
$vmBackupReport | Out-File -Filepath C:\Backupkontrolle_flurin.txt
pause
```

I did create two separate functions already and tried running the Get Data separate from the create Report, which also didnt resolve my error.

If I run the exact same code outside of the Variable `$vmBackupReport` looks something like this (per VM):

```
VM_Name                         : VM_Name_value
VM_ResourceGroupName            : VM_ResourceGroupName_value
VM_BackedUp                     : True
VM_RecoveryVaultName            : VM_RecoveryVaultName_value
VM_RecoveryVaultPolicy          : VM_RecoveryVaultPolicy_value
VM_BackupHealthStatus           : Passed
VM_BackupProtectionStatus       : Healthy
VM_LastBackupStatus             : Completed
VM_LastBackupTime               : 04.10.2023 15:20:34
VM_BackupDeleteState            : NotDeleted
VM_BackupLatestRecoveryPoint    : 04.10.2023 15:20:37
RecoveryVault_ResourceGroupName : RecoveryVault_ResourceGroupName_value
VM_AllRecoveryPoints            : {04.10.2023 15:20:37, 03.10.2023 15:20:59, 02.10.2023 15:20:09, 01.10.2023 15:20:27...}
```

If I run the script within the function there is no value assigned to the variable.

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows just the actual problem "$vmBackupReport is not set"? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well, after I run the Script the Variable is just empty.

Comment: Remove as much as possible from your function that just reproduces the problem. Ignore everything you normally want to do. Just .Add the values you need. Your result is less than 10 lines. Then you make the question clear. You have a problem with the scope of variables. See: Powershell about scope".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually just was, that the `$vmBackupReport` is getting, declared in the Function itself instead of outside. I didnt figure out, why the Variable was completely empty instead of just containing the results of the last run. Whatsoever after removing the line `$vmBackupReport = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()` from the function and moving it down, it worked perfectly.
Final script:

```
Function createReport {
    Write-Host "Collecing Azure virtual machine Information" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
        if(!(gc $path)) {
            Write-Host "Please provide a List of the virtual Machines in this file: 'C:\VmListFlurin.txt'" -BackgroundColor Red
            exit 1
        }
        $vms = @()
        foreach ($vmname in gc $path)
        {
            $vms += Get-AzVM -Name $vmname

            if(!(Get-AzVM -Name $vmname)) {
                Write-Host "VM $($vmname) not found, check VM name and Subscription and try again!" -BackgroundColor Red
            }
            
        }
 
        if($vms) {
            Write-Host "Collecting all Backup Recovery Vault information" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
        }
        else {
            exit 1
        }

        $backupVaults = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault

    #---------------Part 2

    
    foreach ($vm in $vms) 
    {
        $recoveryVaultInfo = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupStatus -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Type 'AzureVM'
        if ($recoveryVaultInfo.BackedUp -eq $true)
        {
            Write-Host "$($vm.Name) - BackedUp : Yes"

            $vmBackupVault = $backupVaults | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq $recoveryVaultInfo.VaultId}


            $container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM -VaultId $vmBackupVault.ID -FriendlyName $vm.Name 
            $backupItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $container -WorkloadType AzureVM -VaultId $vmBackupVault.ID

            #---------------Get All available restore points-------------------------#
            $rententionDays = 730
            $vaultName = $vmBackupVault.Name
            $vaultResourceGroup = $vmBackupVault.ResourceGroupName
            $friendlyName = $vm.name

 
            $vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $vaultResourceGroup -Name $vaultName
            $Container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM -Status Registered -FriendlyName $friendlyName -VaultId $vault.ID
            $BackupItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $Container -WorkloadType AzureVM -VaultId $vault.ID
 
            $startingPoint = -25
            $finishingPoint = 0
            $jobsArray = @()
 
            Do {
 
            $StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($startingPoint)
            $EndDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($finishingPoint)
            $RP = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $BackupItem -StartDate $Startdate.ToUniversalTime() -EndDate $Enddate.ToUniversalTime() -VaultId $vault.ID
            $jobsArray += $RP
            $startingPoint = $startingPoint - 25
            $finishingPoint = $finishingPoint -25
            }until($startingPoint -le -($retentionDays))
 
            #$jobsArray | FT -AutoSize -Property RecoveryPointid, RecoveryPointTime, RecoveryPointType
            #---------------Get All available restore points-------------------------#

            [void]$vmBackupReport.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
            VM_Name = $vm.Name
            VM_ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
            VM_BackedUp = $recoveryVaultInfo.BackedUp
            VM_RecoveryVaultName =  $vmBackupVault.Name
            VM_RecoveryVaultPolicy = $backupItem.ProtectionPolicyName
            VM_BackupHealthStatus = $backupItem.HealthStatus
            VM_BackupProtectionStatus = $backupItem.ProtectionStatus
            VM_LastBackupStatus = $backupItem.LastBackupStatus
            VM_LastBackupTime = $backupItem.LastBackupTime
            VM_BackupDeleteState = $backupItem.DeleteState
            VM_BackupLatestRecoveryPoint = $backupItem.LatestRecoveryPoint
            RecoveryVault_ResourceGroupName = $vmBackupVault.ResourceGroupName
            VM_AllRecoveryPoints = $jobsArray.RecoveryPointTime
        }) 

        

        } 
        else 
        {
            Write-Host "$($vm.Name) - BackedUp : No" -BackgroundColor DarkRed
            $vmBackupVault = $null
            $container =  $null
            $backupItem =  $null
        } 
        
        
    }
}

$vmBackupReport = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$path = "C:\VmListTest.txt"
Set-AzContext -Subscription "Test/PreProd" | out-null
createReport;

$path = "C:\VmListProd.txt"
Set-AzContext -Subscription "Produktion" | out-null
createReport;

$script:vmBackupReport
```

Comment: As an aside: [try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60708578/1701026) as it is ineffective.